# AWS stepfunction array job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, aws-pipeline

I want to make one of AWS job as an array job(to execute things parallely), I have list of inputs for the child job in single json file on s3.

I am trying to convert the job into array job by adding array job into defination as follows:

```
"Array": {
        "Source": "S3",
        "Bucket": "some bucket",
        "Path": "path/abc.json",
        "SuccessPercent": 100
      }
```

Here, abc.json is the file that contains all the inputs for the child job,
but specifying it as "path", AWS is trying to fetch multiple files from that location, I know, the path should be mentioned as "Key" : "path/abc.json", but without the Path variable, I am getting an error of validation,

How could I use that file for the child job execution, or what should I mention in path variable.

Answer (score 1):

The Map step is for iterating over array.'

But before that, you need to read input from the file and get the array, if i understood it correctly ?

So i would solve it with 1 steps.

1 = lambda, that consumes your input, reads the file and gives back a json which contains the inputs.

2 = Map step, what iterates over the results from previous step.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html